# Is there a way to stage all changed files before a commit?

Tags: smartgit

Right now I'm manually selecting each changed file for staging before committing. I'm curious whether there's a SmartGit equivalent to

```
git commit -a
```

perhaps a shortcut to select all changed files (other than those being .gitignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having selected the repository root directory in the **Repositories** view and having the focus in this view, operations like **Stage** and **Commit** will work on all available files, *regardless* of which files are currently visible in the **Files** view (e.g. you might have selected to hide *untracked* files).

Answer (score 1):

You can select all changed files in the Files pane with standard OS shortcut. On Windows this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then you can stage the selection as usual.

Note though that if you are going to commit only the whole files, you don't even need to stage them. After you selected files of interest, you can press Commit, and then make sure the "Local Changes" option is picked on the top of the dialog. SmartGit will stage and commit selected files for you automatically.